# Does the word "supercalifragilisticexpialidocious" exist?

Tags: etymology, adjectives

I have heard about the word countless times. However, when I looked up the dictionary, I could not find it. So I would like to ask if the word even exists at all. If so, what does the word actually mean and why was it invented?

This word really piqued my curiosity I could not resist asking.

Comment: The word [has its own Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious)

Comment: Hey guys I am terribly sorry for putting up such a seemingly useless question. However, I do not trust wikipedia completely and wanted to refer to you guys for the best answers I hope you understand how I feel so please do not vote down my question. I have already flagged it and request that it be deleted. Please reconsider your down vote

Comment: It's got an entry at [oxford dictionaries online](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/supercalifragilisticexpialidocious?q=supercalifragilisticexpialidocious)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a nonsense word made famous from a song of the same name in the 1964 Mary Poppins film.

It has an entry in the Oxford English Dictionary:

> A nonsense word, originally used esp. by children, and typically expressing excited approbation: fantastic, fabulous.

The first mention before the film is the title of another song, Supercalafajalistickespialadojus, written by G. Parker & B. Young in 1949. Parker and Young attempted to sue the film-makers for copyright infringement, but, according  to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious#Legal_action):

> The Disney publishers won the lawsuit partially because affidavits were produced showing that "variants of the word were known ... many years prior to 1949".

Comment: Does it have any meaning at all?

Comment: Ignore my earlier comment. According to a wikipedia article, the word means:"Something to say when there is nothing to say"

Comment: @David Toh, it's primary usage is to make yourself sound precocious (if you say it loud enough)